# EthereumJ: Private Network: How to I set my sender account?

Tags: ethereumj

I'm currently using EthereumJ and I'm trying out a use case to send an amount to a specific account in my own private chain. But I'm getting this error:

> Not enough cash: Require: 14000000000000001, Sender cash: 0]

I've written some basic codes and used some of the codes provided in the sample.

```
JsonRpcImpl jsonRpc = new JsonRpcImpl(blockchainImpl,compositeEthereumListener);
jsonRpc.setRepository(repository);

Account account = jsonRpc.addAccount("ngzhongqin@gmail.com");

try {
    logger.info("Test-account:address"+account.getAddress());
    String address = TypeConverter.toJsonHex(account.getAddress());
    servletObject.setJsonObject("balance",account.getBalance());
    servletObject.setJsonObject("address",address);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Map<ByteArrayWrapper, Account> accountMap = jsonRpc.getAccounts();
logger.info("Test-accountMap:"+accountMap);

try {
    sendTxAndWait(account.getAddress(), new byte[0]);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the `sendTxAndWait` Method from the Example:

```
private TransactionReceipt sendTxAndWait(byte[] receiveAddress, byte[] data) throws InterruptedException {

    byte[] senderPrivateKey = Hex.decode("");
    byte[] fromAddress = ECKey.fromPrivate(senderPrivateKey).getAddress();
    BigInteger nonce = ApiServer.ethereum.getRepository().getNonce(fromAddress);
    Transaction tx = new Transaction(
        ByteUtil.bigIntegerToBytes(nonce),
        ByteUtil.longToBytesNoLeadZeroes(ApiServer.ethereum.getGasPrice()),
        ByteUtil.longToBytesNoLeadZeroes(200000),
        receiveAddress,
        ByteUtil.bigIntegerToBytes(BigInteger.valueOf(1)),  // 1_000_000_000 gwei, 1_000_000_000_000L szabo, 1_000_000_000_000_000L finney, 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L ether
        data);

    tx.sign(ECKey.fromPrivate(senderPrivateKey));
    logger.info("<=== Sending transaction: " + tx);
    ApiServer.ethereum.submitTransaction(tx);

    return waitForTx(tx.getHash());
}
```

Method `waitForTx` from the example:

```
private TransactionReceipt waitForTx(byte[] txHash) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<ByteArrayWrapper, TransactionReceipt> txWaiters =
            Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<ByteArrayWrapper, TransactionReceipt>());

    ByteArrayWrapper txHashW = new ByteArrayWrapper(txHash);
    txWaiters.put(txHashW, null);
    long startBlock = ApiServer.ethereum.getBlockchain().getBestBlock().getNumber();

    while(true) {
        TransactionReceipt receipt = txWaiters.get(txHashW);
        if (receipt != null) {
            return receipt;
        } else {
            long curBlock = ApiServer.ethereum.getBlockchain().getBestBlock().getNumber();
            if (curBlock > startBlock + 16) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The transaction was not included during last 16 blocks: " + txHashW.toString().substring(0,8));
            } else {
                logger.info("Waiting for block with transaction 0x" + txHashW.toString().substring(0,8) +
                        " included (" + (curBlock - startBlock) + " blocks received so far) ...");

            }
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            wait(20000);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I use the account `102e61f5d8f9bc71d0ad4a084df4e65e05ce0e1c` stated in the frontier-morden.json

```
{
    "nonce": "0x00006d6f7264656e",
    "difficulty": "0x020000",
    "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD8",
    "alloc": {
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1" },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1" },
        "102e61f5d8f9bc71d0ad4a084df4e65e05ce0e1c": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the transaction 'value' to `2100000000000000000L`.
Increase the gas limit for the time being to be `3_000_000`. If you are attempting to create a contract or write to a contract function that is not `payable` then make sure you the 'value' field is `0`. Ensure your `.conf` file is pointing to the correct genesis block so that it registers the funds.

My genesis block is similar to yours:

`"alloc": {
   "31e2e1ed11951c7091dfba62cd4b7145e947219c": {
     "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
   }
  }`

Reference in my .conf file as : `genesis = sample-genesis.json`.

I'd double check that you're signing with the correct key corresponding to the account that you've loaded with funds. 
I've found Ethereumj to work better as a client via a REST service. I've yet to use it's JsonRpc functionality. I know [Web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) has a good service for this.